# Передать значение выбранного select в onclick

Tags: javascript, select

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно передать значение выбранного select в onclick.

Вот мой кусок кода, он рабочий:

```html
    <a onclick="ipayCheckout({
    amount: Цена,
    currency:'RUB',
    order_number:'',
    description: 'Описание'})">ссылка</a>
```

Мне нужно подставлять цену в пункт amount из select, но как это сделать даже в голову не приходит и можно ли так вообще?) Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
amount: document.getElementById('select id').value,
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог)

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <a onclick="ipayCheckout({
    amount: Цена,
    currency:'RUB',
    order_number:'',
    description: 'Описание'})">ссылка</a>
```

а почему такая конструкция? не лучше ли работать датасетами?
как минимум можно было написать так:

```js
function getInfo(p){
  console.log(p.dataset.id)
}
```

```html
<a href="#" data-id="1" onclick="getInfo(this);">click me</a>
```

ну дальше как предлагал Igor...

Comment: Я больше с пхп и html, js сложно дается) Спасибо за совет)